# How to change even numbers to odd in a String for java?

Tags: java

Given a string, you will change each number from an odd to an even number or even
numbers to odds.  For this program, social security numbers have a hyphen – at position 3 and at position 6.  Print out the new number.

Example input:

472-19-1267

Example Output:

583-28-2378

So far I have:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter your social security number ")
String social = input.nextLine();
for(int i = 0; i< social.length(); i++){

    char c = social.charAt(i);
}
```

Edit: Something I for got to mention was that the example I gave was just an example of what could be the input(so when the output adds 1 or subtracts 1 you don't have to do it like that you can choose if you want to add or subtract). The input could be any numbers with that form. Second, the numbers have to be random for example you can't make it all 1's.

Comment: An easy trick is that, if X is an integer, then X ^ 1 changes it from odd to even or from even to odd. "^" is the exclusive OR operator. Take you string number, parse it into an integer, xor it with 1, convert it back to string.

Comment: This question is not clear: No "direction" defined for the changing. For example, the second character shows Input 7 -> Output 8, means "if c is odd then **ADD** 1", but the 6th character shows Input 9 -> Output 8, means "if c is odd then **MINUS** 1", this is confusing.

Comment: #1 Why 9 -> 8 when 8 is from 7? #2 The algorithm is just to iterate the string, search the number, convert to odd or even, then replace it in the original string. That's all. In which part do you need help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      String social = "472-19-1267";
      String result ="";
         System.out.println("[INPUT] : " + social) ;
        for(int i = 0; i< social.length(); i++){ //this is to loop social string
             char c = social.charAt(i);
             if (c!='-') //check if the character is not -
             {
              if ( c % 2 == 0 ) //check if the character is even 
             {
               int cresult=Character.getNumericValue(c);   //check cast the character to integer for doing add or subtract 
                 cresult = cresult+1; //add the result with +1
                 result += Integer.toString(cresult).charAt(0); //cast the int back to character
                  
             }
             else
             {
              //if character is odd
               int cresult=Character.getNumericValue(c);  
                 cresult = cresult+1;
                 if (cresult >= 10) //check if character is 9 +1 = 10 so i will change it to subtract to to make it -1 (10-2=8)
                 {
                     cresult = cresult-2; 
                 }
                   result += Integer.toString(cresult).charAt(0); //this line will append the result with cresult
             }   
             }
             else
             {
                 result += c; //this line will append the result with -
             }
        }
        System.out.println("[RESULT] : " + result) ;
    }
    
}
```

the result as below

```
[INPUT] : 472-19-1267
[RESULT] : 583-28-2378
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
static final Pattern NUMBER = Pattern.compile("\\d");

static String changeOddEven(String s) {
    return NUMBER.matcher(s).replaceAll(
        m -> "" + (Integer.parseInt(m.group()) ^ 1));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(changeOddEven("472-19-1267"));
    System.out.println(changeOddEven("000-19-9999"));
}
```

output:

```
563-08-0376
111-08-8888
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that picks the even/odd value at random:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your social security number ");
    String social = input.nextLine();

    Random r = new Random();
    String evens = "02468";
    String odds = "13579";
    String output = "";
    for(int i = 0; i<social.length(); i++){
      char c = social.charAt(i);
      if (evens.indexOf(c) != -1) {
        output = output + odds.charAt(r.nextInt(odds.length()));
      }
      else if (odds.indexOf(c) != -1) {
        output = output + evens.charAt(r.nextInt(evens.length()));
      }
      else {
        output = output + c;
      }
    }    
    System.out.println(output);
  }
```